# how do i convert a random network.list into a igraph object?

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a nework.list object and I would like to calculate the network summaries for each individual network in the network.list.
as I was not able to get them directly from the network list I'm trying to transform it into an igraph object.
This is the code that I use so far:

```
# Set the number of simulations to perform
n_sim <- 100
# Generate n_sim random networks from lpm_3
sim_networks <- simulate(lpm_3, nsim = n_sim)
class(sim_networks)
# Convert sim_networks to a list of igraph objects
sim_igraphs <- lapply(sim_networks, asIgraph)
Error in UseMethod("asIgraph") : 
  no applicable method for 'asIgraph' applied to an object of class "formula"
```

I was trying to get summaries like the network density or diameter

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! It looks like you're already basically there. The following code works on my machine:

```
library(ergm)
library(intergraph)

n_sim <- 100

data(flo)
g <- as.network(flo)
m <- ergm(g ~ edges)

sim_networks <- simulate(m, nsim = n_sim)

sim_igraphs <- lapply(sim_networks, asIgraph)

summary(sapply(sim_igraphs, igraph::edge_density))
summary(sapply(sim_igraphs, igraph::diameter))
```

Can you check the class of `lpm_3`, or show how it's built? Happy to edit my answer if the problem is not solved.